# Error loading dataset in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a dataset that i can see it in a preview:

[image]

But, when I create a source in a dataflow, and i choose that dataset, the flow doesn´t import the rows, only the columns name:

[image]

Please, someone can help me with this problem, I don´t know why the source doesn´t import the rows correctly.

I tried creating the dataset again, as an dataset and inserted but it doesn´t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Projection, Click **Import Projection**.

[image]

- Once imported projection, you can click data preview tab.
- Click `Refetch from sources` under refresh drop down option.

[image]

- You can also check the Row limit value in debug settings. It should not be `0`.

[image]

Comment: It didn´t work, the projection it´s working, It´s gettings the columns but not the content of the dataset, and the file have around 200.000 rows and the debut settings are signend in 1.000.000 so that´s not the problem, thank you for your options

Comment: Did you click `Refetch from sources` once again in Data preview tab?

Comment: Yes, I did it but continues showing only the column names but not the rows data, the dataset were creating by doing a merge from different files, I don´t know if maybe could be something wrong in this previous step I did, I used the copy data tool for this.

Comment: Are you using the same sink dataset that you created for copy activity here?

Comment: Yes, I created a new file from the sink in the copy tool, and I´m using this file as a source in the data flow and is with this file that I have the problem.

Comment: Are you using the same dataset, or creating new dataset for that file?

Comment: I merged lot of files in a new dataset and I´m taking that new dataset as a source in the data flow.

Comment: No, Dataset and files are different. Did you merge all files into one file? Did you create new dataset for that file in Dataflow?

Comment: Yes, I merged all the files into a new file, and them, I created a new dataset in my data flow, that dataset is the file created from the merged files.

Comment: Is it only happening in `Data preview?` If pipeline containing this dataflow is debugged, does it got executed successfully with correct data as output?

Comment: You were right, when I executed the pipeline, it works and the data flow run perfectly, thank you so much